# Uni-directional one-to-many in GORM

Tags: grails, grails-orm

This might be really simple.

I have two domain classes - Member and GroupOfMembers.

```
class Member
{
    String memberName
}

class GroupOfMembers
{
    String groupName

    static hasMany = [members : Member]
}
```

As seen in above code, a Member can exist without a group or can be associated with one or more groups.

I am trying to figure out GORM query where I can list all groups to which a given member is associated with. The schema generated in this case has a join table for the two entities.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you haven't already figured this out try this for a particular member:

```
def groupList = GroupOfMembers.createCriteria().list {
    members {
        eq('id', member.id)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kelly. 
This definitely works. 
My requirement changed a bit however. Now the relationship is Many-To-Many.

So I created a new entity:-


class Membership{
    User member
    GroupOfMembers   group
    
    //validation constraints
    // functions for save,update and delete Memberships 
}

This way it is cleaner to query from both the ends.